# Save Images form Word with opening Excel

Tags: vba, ms-word

Current Code Working fine Saving Images from word  through below code

```
If singleline.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
Dim shp4 As InlineShape
Dim mchart4 As Shape
Set shp4 = singleline.Range.InlineShapes(1)
shp4.Select
Selection.Copy
Set mchart4 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart(xl3DAreaStacked, , , shp4.Width, shp4.Height)
mchart4.Chart.Paste
mchart4.Chart.Export ("c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png")
mchart4.Chart.Delete
b64strng = ConvertFileToBase64("c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png")
datainbtw = Replace(datainbtw, "<p>", " ")
datainbtw = Replace(datainbtw, "</p>", " ")
datainbtw = datainbtw + "<img src=\'data:image/png;base64," + b64strng + "\' style=\'Display:block\'>"
datainbtw = Replace(datainbtw, "/" & vbCr & " <", "<")

Kill "c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png"
End If
```

Here every Image saving before  Excel Opens chart and Getting closed after Image Save.

we don't want excel to open chart, is there any way to save image without opening excel popup

thanks

Comment: You might be able to change the visible property of the Excel sheet, if that would help. ScreenUpdating is also a property that you may want to change to False (toggling back when your procedure finishes).

Comment: thanks for comment 
i got ScreenUpdating 
but  visible property of the Excel sheet can you please add the code to above where to add and code

Comment: Sorry, without your full code and sample files, that is beyond my skillset. *(It may be even with those.)* Try with just the screenupdating.