# How to make invisible excel chart

Tags: vba, ms-word

this code in VBA Generates popup excel and Closed Automatically . Here How can This make visible false

```
Set mchart1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart(xl3DAreaStacked, , , shp1.Width, shp1.Height)
```

thanks

Comment: What does "Generates popup excel" means?

Comment: chart opens on excel

Comment: Then, what does "Closed Automatically" mean?

Comment: chart popup closed in seconds

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly you are asking. *This code* shows only that a chart is created, nothing about closing Excel. You need to show more of your code, describe what is does and what you want it to (not) do.

Comment: Yes Code create chart.  Now requirement is  need to hide the chart  ( Don't show)

here code :
If singleline.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
Dim shp1 As InlineShape
Dim mchart1 As Shape
Set shp1 = singleline.Range.InlineShapes(1)
shp1.Select
Selection.Copy
Set mchart1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart(xl3DAreaStacked, , , shp1.Width, shp1.Height)
mchart1.Chart.Paste
mchart1.Chart.Export ("c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png")
End If

Comment: Let us better clarify the issue: Creating a chart in Word, involves an Excel window, where the chart is really built. Do you want **that Excel window** to be hidden?

Comment: yes   Excel window need to hidden

Comment: This question is simply a duplicate of the one you asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656596/save-images-form-word-with-opening-excel

Comment: OK. Do you **really** wont it to be hidden (but the Excel session will be kept), or you want quitting that excel session?

Comment: want hidden  sir

Comment: Then, test my answer suggestion, please and send some feedback.

Comment: big day saved lot thank you sir ..  mchart1.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit   this worked after create Quit  . because excel sheets taking memory that's why issue raised .. thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. But you could make your question clearer. I couldn't understand what you want only reading it... And, it is good to write your comment after my answer code. Somebody else searching for something similar will understand which is the most appropriate solution. No need to read all our comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next code line:

```
mchart1.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Visible = False
```

But do you need them sometimes to be visible and do something with them?

If you iterate many times and your code creates many such Excel charts, your memory will be occupied with a lot of useless garbage...

If you will understand my concern, you can change the above solution in:

```
mchart1.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit
```